# Lorem Ipsum extension for Brackets not working

Tags: html, keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-brackets, ubuntu-18.04, lorem-ipsum

I have installed the *Lorem Ipsum* extension by *Lance Campbell* in my *Brackets* version *1.13 build 1.13.0-17696*

As explained in this [Github](https://github.com/lkcampbell/brackets-lorem-ipsum) site

I am creating a HTML file and then inside the *body* element I am typing `lorem` followed by:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

But nothing is happening. Why is it so?

I am using *Ubuntu 18.04*

I have already checked all my system keyboard shortcuts and there is no conflict.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to assign another shortcut to lorem?

Answer (score 1):

Type plain text *lorem* and then press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine this was overridden by Radeon video driver settings global shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

HTML files

```
lorem + tab
```

other files we use

```
Press F1
Select Lorem ipsum from the list
```

This is for VS-code

Answer (score 0):

write :
lorem and click : ctrl+shift+l
you can type lorem_wrap10 ( for letters in one row )